# How To Apply Stirlings Formula to find values of $n$ such that ${n \choose k} 2^{1- {k \choose 2}}<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, analysis

$k$ is a fixed natural number! I am supposed to obtain that the biggest n possible is no larger than $ k 2^{k/2} [\sqrt(2)/e + o(1)]$, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Is there a typo in the title? Whenever $a\ge 2$, we have $a2^{1-a}<1$, so I do not see how $\binom{n}k2^{1-\binom{n}k}<1$ would imply that about $n$.

Comment: There is a typo, thank you!!!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4103528/177399 for an answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest No, my bound in that answer is much less precise. I do not use Stirling's formula.